# Move the pointer and control it with the head

Tags: touchscreen, accessibility, input-methods, mouse, touch

My name is Stéphane. I am disabled (quadriplegic).

I have a Mac Os 10.15.7 computer where I can move my mouse pointer with my head [with this system](https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/guide/mac-help/mchlb2d4782b/mac) and with my webcam.

Is there a way with Android to use the webcam to move the cursor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Stéphane! Although I am not personally aware of such a system, I imagine at least one does exist. Accessibility functionality on Android is fairly advanced, and I have a hunch a system exactly like what you describe is available. I'm sorry I can't be of more help in that regards.

As a possible simple alternative, years ago a quadriplegic colleague of mine was a computer programmer at a very prominent tech company.  He would strap a pencil-like device to his forehead using a specially-designed headband and write computer programs.  Instead of a pencil tip, the tip of the device was more like an eraser.  Back then, there were no touch screens, so he would be pressing physical keyboard keys.  I wonder if something similar would work for you, but with a tip that works with touchscreens.

Another quadriplegic friend had short 10-15cm (4-6") arms that were rounded at the ends. At the ends of each (or just one... I don't exactly recall) small appendage, was a small ~1cm cavity in which he could attach tools, including a similar pencil-like device (with an eraser-like tip) which he used to type.  He even drove a customized vehicle (a large van that had a wheelchair lift).

I don't know, but maybe some of the above gives you ideas!

I also have a hunch that organizations that help quadriplegics and paraplegics would have good resources for exactly the type of system about which you inquire.  I know that for people with very limited vision or blindness that there are some amazing organizations that help locate (and possibly help fund) obtaining tools like you describe to help accommodate their needs.  I imagine (and hope) similar organizations exist for quadriplegics and paraplegics.

In summary, I hope someone else here will be able to offer you a more specific answer to you question, but in the meantime, that at least a little bit of what I wrote will be of help to you.